# PostgreSQL: How to link 2 tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key

I have a table defined like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.journeys (
  journey_id uuid NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  name text NOT NULL,
  user_id uuid NOT NULL,
  date_created timestamptz NOT NULL,
  date_deleted timestamptz NULL,
  route_id uuid NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_users
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id)
      REFERENCES users(user_id)
);
```

What I want to do now is create a second table that will connect to this table above.  Here's its definition:

```
CREATE TABLE public.routes (
  route_id uuid NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  idx smallint NOT NULL,
  date timestamptz NULL,
  latitude real NOT NULL,
  longitude real NOT NULL,  
  CONSTRAINT route_key 
    PRIMARY KEY (route_id, idx),
  CONSTRAINT fk_journeys
    FOREIGN KEY(route_id)
      REFERENCES journeys(route_id)
);
```

The notion is that for every Journey there will be a connected Route that simply consists of a series of Latitude, Longitude points.  So for a given `route_id` in `journeys` there will be `N` records in `routes`.  Every record in a given route will share the same `route_id` but each one will have a unique `idx` (ie. 0, 1, 2, ...).

This is the error I'm getting when I try creating `public.routes`:

```
SQL Error [42830]: ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "journeys"
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix this?

Robert

Comment: You need a unique constraint (index) in your table `journeys` for the column `route_id`. The error message really is self-explanatory. You may need an intermediate `n-n` table between these two to fix your schema.

Answer (score 1):

I read several more threads on the subject and then realized that that `journeys.route_id` was not being declared as `UNIQUE`.

So within the `public.journeys` declaration, this fixed the problem:

```
route_id uuid NOT NULL UNIQUE,
```

Comment: Although defining it a unique eliminates the error for  consistency better to define `routes.route_id`  as the primary key.

Comment: But `routes.route_id` is not the primary key for that table.  The combination of `route_id` and `idx` together are.